# Looking for an Objective Function package in Julia

Tags: function, optimization, package, julia

I am trying to identify/source an objective function package in Julia that has common objective functions (such as Rastrigin, Schwefel, etc.) in-built, so I do not need to retype the function via an `f(x) = ...` declaration.

Does such a package exist, and if so, what is it called?

Comment: Does https://github.com/jonathanBieler/BlackBoxOptimizationBenchmarking.jl provide what you're looking for? (If so, I'll add it as an answer.)

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaSmoothOptimizers/OptimizationProblems.jl for use with https://github.com/JuliaSmoothOptimizers